# How to receive value when clicking on href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I receive from Spring to UI this code:

```
<div th:each="answer: ${allSearch}">
    <div class="pic">
        <a href="#" onclick="toSelectedObject()" style="text-decoration: none">
            <input type="hidden" name="photoId" id="photoId" th:value="${answer.photo}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" th:value="${answer.id}" />
            <img th:attr="src=${answer.photo}" width="220" height="280" />
            <div align="center">
                <b>   <span th:text="${answer.name}">Name</span></b>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I recive many photos(href) from various data bases. I want to recive photo value, becouse I will use "split" for understanding from what DB was this photo. After that I will do window.location.href to right direction. When I used one DB my href was like this

```
<a th:href="@{~/selectedPage(hiddenModelId=${selected.id})}" style="text-decoration: none">
```

Now I can't do so, becouse I have a different `selectedPage`.
I try to do like so:

```
var photo;
var id;

function toSelectedObject(){
    photo = $("#photoId").val();
    id = $("#id").val();
    alert("ID: "+id + "  photo: "+photo);
}
```

But I always see id and photo only the first image. I don't understand, why?
I try to with class:

```
 <input type="hidden" class="photoId" th:value="${curtain.photo}"/>
 <input type="hidden" class="id" th:value="${curtain.id}"/>
```

But it's the same. I think problem becouse I have identical classes or id. Becouse every `div` have identical classes or id, but with different informations

Comment: The problem is because you cannot have duplicate `id` attributes within a page. Change the `id` to a class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div th:each="answer: ${allSearch}">
    <div class="pic">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
            <input type="hidden" name="photoId" id="photoId" th:value="${answer.photo}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" th:value="${answer.id}" />
            <img th:attr="src=${answer.photo}" width="220" height="280" />
            <div align="center">
                <b>   <span th:text="${answer.name}">Name</span></b>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('.pic a').on('click', function (e) {
    var photo = $(this).find('input[name=photoId]').val();
    var id = $(this).find('input[name=id]').val();
    alert("ID: "+id + "  photo: "+photo);
})
</script>
```